# Selfhosted WCF not running Factory(CustomHostServiceFactory)?

Tags: wcf, iis, factory, self-hosting, service-factory

I have a WCF service that can be placed in both IIS7 and in selfhost. The SVC file looks like this :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="False" Service="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.MyAppClientService" Factory="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.CustomHostServiceFactory"%>
```

The problem is that the CustomHostServiceFactory will not be runned if the serivce is selfhosted? Is there a way to get this to work?

When running from IIS7 it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to run the init code manually when using selfhost.